# Not able to close wheel nav

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do i open wheelnav on button click and close it if the same button is clicked again?
I used piemenu.removeWheel() for the second case but as soon as i use it the wheel does not even appear

Here is my code:

```
<script>
var i=0;
var piemenu = new wheelnav('piemenu');
piemenu.spreaderInTitle = icon.plus;
piemenu.spreaderOutTitle = icon.cross;
piemenu.spreaderRadius = piemenu.wheelRadius * 0.13;
piemenu.clockwise = false;
piemenu.sliceInitPathFunction = piemenu.slicePathFunction;
piemenu.initPercent = 0.1;
piemenu.wheelRadius = piemenu.wheelRadius * 0.83;
piemenu.navItemsContinuous = true;
piemenu.sliceAngle = 36;
function make(){
 if(i==0){
 i=1;
 piemenu.createWheel();
 piemenu.setTooltips(['help','friend 
 request','create','privacy','settings','signout','download']);
 }else
 {
  i=0;
  piemenu.removeWheel();
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you share the code for the `wheelnav` function?

Comment: @Optimae wheelnav is a built-in function in wheelnav.js

Comment: Wat do you mean by close wheel?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question is wheel doesn't appear when clicked again. Wheel will reappear after clicking the button if the code is modified as below.

```
else { i=0; piemenu.removeWheel(); }
```

Comment: Sorry,The code was the same as you have given.By mistake i wrote i=1 here.When i add piemenu.removewheel(),i start getting the following error    Uncaught TypeError: raphael.pathToRelative is not a function
    at new wheelnavTitle (wheelnav.js:1695)
    at wheelnavItem.initPathsAndTransforms (wheelnav.js:1562)
    at wheelnavItem.createNavItem (wheelnav.js:942)
    at wheelnav.createWheel (wheelnav.js:280)
    at make ((index):269)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick ((index):118) which i was not getting befor adding piemenu.remove();

Comment: I tried to recreate the issue. But couldn't. Could you give complete code to recreate the issue.

Comment: Here is the link..there is the code but there is no output,Sorry for that

Comment: Can you share wheelnav js lib path. I've included "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/wheelnav/1.7.0/wheelnav.min.js" but I'm getting Raphael is not defined

Comment: Whenever i'm using removeWheel().I'm getting the same error.Remove removeWheel() and the error will go